# Why we use functions in model?

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a project in Laravel and I saw that there are functions in models.
It is hard for me because I don't know why they are here.

For example function like:

```
public function lowest()
{
    return $this->prices->min('price');
}
```

Can you explain me this?

Comment: That function gives you the lowest price.

Comment: Model is a normal class but because it represent a database table structure thats why its a model, so a normal class can have function. If you declare a function in model, you are able to easily get the content of the table for manipulation.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting down-votes because this is not a Stack Overflow question where you get support on code issues. This is an inquisitive question. I'd point you to [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) to learn more. As a short answer, the model might represent an idea or even an object. Let's say that we are talking about a person. This person belongs to a family, so a function might return an instance of Family so you can list all of the people in that family. The person can also have many kids. Rather than store these kids in an array in a field, these kids can be other people too, and a method on the model can be called to return objects representing each kid as another person.

This is a long concept to explain, so I really do recommend researching on a site geared for learning/researching and not debugging/fixing.

Hopefully my answer gets you started though!